# how can i save the excel from kendo spreadsheet into a remote server using some thing like

Tags: excel, kendo-ui, telerik, kendospreadsheet

how can i save the excel from kendo spreadsheet into a remote server using some thing like

```
var spreadsheet = $("#spreadsheet").data("kendoSpreadsheet"); 
spreadsheet.saveAsExcel();
```

saves excel to client machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this in the `excelExport` events of the `Kendo SpreadSheet`.

Use the following code:

```
excelExport: function(e) {
    // Prevent the default behavior which will prompt the user to save the generated file.
    e.preventDefault();

    // Get the Excel file as a data URL.
    var dataURL = new kendo.ooxml.Workbook(e.workbook).toDataURL();

    // Strip the data URL prologue.
    var base64 = dataURL.split(";base64,")[1];

    // Post the base64 encoded content to the server which can save it.
    $.post("/server/save", {
        base64: base64,
        fileName: "ExcelExport.xlsx"
    });
}
```

You can read further about this in Kendo's documentation [here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/data-management/grid/excel-export#saving-files-on-server). This page is for exporting to excel from a `Kendo Grid` but it's exactly the same for the `SpreadSheet`.

Comment: yes  .  Byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(Base);
            File.WriteAllBytes(@"c:\"+name, bytes);